# SQL - an alias was previously found when using over() in old mysql version

Tags: mysql, sql

A sql query didn't work in old version of mysql below 8:

```
SELECT count(*) OVER() AS d FROM `T`
```

It gives this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '() AS FULLCOUNT FROM T' at line 1

You can refer to this DBFiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7dd651e5b2c988a7a85c76a2c83df066

to test the query with different versions.

then tell me how can I solve that issue without upgrade mysql version
because I don't have access of that server

Comment: So...whats your question, exactly? You're right, this feature doesn't exist before MySQL 8. If you want to use it, use an up to date version of MySQL.

Comment: if I could upgrade sql version then I would be definitely do that. but I can't have access of that server .I want to run this  what should I modifiy to run

Comment: There's nothing you can do - it's not supported in 5.7 or below. If you want this feature, either create a new server, upgrade your current one, or rent one from someone else.

Comment: so I would have to change query in two parts for that working. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way :

```
SELECT (select COUNT(*)  as d FROM T) as d
FROM T;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jrgWDUfjBiT8aHKNuNbroD/0)